# Defining external subroutines in dsPIC30F family

Tags: assembly, call, extern, pic

I'm having trouble migrating from a PIC18F device to a dsPIC30F (4013 in particular). I'm using MPLAB with ASM30 as compiler. So as the subject suggests the issue are extern subroutines - and by that I mean defined in a different source file. In the 18F's it was nice and simple: lets say I have a procedure called "initiateData" in a source file "init.asm" and I want to call it from "main.asm" - nothing easier then that: just place a

```
EXTERN initiateData
```

in the main.asm and

```
GLOBAL initiateData
```

in init.asm. Then just call it from main:

```
call initiateData
```

However for the dsPIC30 I try something like this (init.s)

```
.global initiateData

.text

initiateData:
MOV #0x0400, W2 
return
.end
```

and (main.s):

```
.equ __30F4013, 1
.include "P30F4013.inc"
.extern initiateData
.global __reset

.text
__reset:

call initiateData
.end
```

This code (although in reality is more complicated - I just posted a summary of what i think is important) compiles and links correctly (but with a irritating warning: main.s:0: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted - how do I fix that?). The problem here is, that in debug mode the tracker (oh yeah - I use PICkit2 for debugging) enters inititateData as it's supposed to but at the mov command there's an error and the program counter jumps to location

```
0100  DA4000  ReservedBR
0102  FE0000  reset
```

Causing another __reset call.
I don't really know what I'm doing wrong - there's not a lot on the web on how to make a multiple source project in asm30 so I humbly ask for any help.

Regards,

drinker

Comment: If it enters `initiateData` correctly, why do you think the problem is with extern subroutines? If you inline the `MOV` does the problem go away?

Comment: @ckhan yes - if I move the "mov" from init.s into main.s - the problem disapears

Comment: @ckhan but just to note just moving the mov dosn't really solve anything because same thing occurs on the next command in initiateData: "clr temp01". I'm at my wits end with this